# Emulate Netbeans behavior in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, hotkeys

I'm currently switching from Netbeans to Eclipse. In Netbeans, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a line with an error or warning will cause a dialogue to pop up with suggested fixes.

In Eclipse, the same dialogue can be shown, but I have to hover over the error/warning with my mouse. The "focus" hotkey doesn't seem to do anything except allow the dialogue to remain open.

Is there any way to emulate the Netbeans dialogue behavior in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse this feature is called ***Quick Fix* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)**: see [Eclipse help: *Quick Fix and Quick Assist*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-quickfix-assist.htm)

Shortcuts can be changed in *Window > Preferences: General > Keys* (by default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is bound to the command *Properties*).